# Computer under Ubuntu 12.04 randomly locking up when inactive

Tags: logging, lock

I am sure someone has had a similar problem somewhere in the world, but I've not really been able to find a way out of this.

My install is as clean as I can make it (what can you do wrong with Ubuntu! ;)), and the computer is running smoothly. But every now and then, randomly, and only when not in use (often over night), it sometimes locks up. The computer then doesn't respond to my mouse or keyboard (where for example I cannot change the status of Num Lock or Caps Lock - the light stays on), the screen remains blank, and I need to restart the computer using the front-button. If this was every 6 months or so, it wouldn't bother me at all, but this is more along the lines of 1-2 times a week now...although I couldn't estimate if it is regular, or more or less than "before".

There should really be no particular activity running (that isn't running when I'm on the computer) that would cause my PC to lock when inactive...

My question now is, what would be the best approach to solving the problem? I am guessing, logging activity to look for suspicious processes? How would I go best about logging this, and if I do, would someone be willing to have a look at the output and try to help? :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

bisi

Comment: Actually, there is a log-file-viewer pre-installed, and it would seem that shows what I was loooking for. But apart from an hourly "CRON[6575]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)", it doesn't show anything in the logfile... the 6 last messages were the same... any hints?

Comment: Do you have a usb keyboard? My keyboard locks up every couple of days, but I found that if I unplug it and plug it back in, it immediately functions again.

Comment: Actually, here is a slightly different line before it crashed: CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )) ... would that mean anything odd?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your system overclocked it may cause issues. I was having the same problems with full lockups and failing to resume     after suspend. I also disabled pll over volt and any other things that my computer doesn't need and i haven't had a lock up in a week, hope this helps you.